# Root of function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, numerical-methods, transcendental-equations

Can you find root of the equation $$f(k)=1+(1-k^2)\ln(1+\frac{1}{k})?$$
I tried to use Matlab command but it does not give me any result. Can you suggest a method to find root of equation.

Comment: From plotting the function it looks like there is a root near $k=1.8$. There is likely no closed-form representation for this root. You've tagged this question with [tag:numerical-methods], so I would suggest using such an approach (say, Newton's method) for your problem.

Comment: approx $k=1.80898678$

Comment: Relevant MATLAB commands: f=@(k)1+(1-k.^2).*log(1+1./k); x=fzero(f,[1,2]); Returns $x=1.808986784539572$ for which the residual $f(x)$ is evaluated as $-4u$, where $u$ is the double precision roundoff error $u = 2^{-53}$.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you have the variable both inside and outside log/exp functions, it's hopless to think you can get a closed-form solution in terms of elementary functions.

You can usually get by with only a calculator by using iterative methods. Essentially, just try to express one of the occurences of $k$, put in an initial condition, repeat the process a couple of times and you're there. There are convergence conditions to test that I usually ignore and do it by trial and error (if the values explode to nonsense values, I just pick another $k$ and express that one).

What worked:

$$k=\sqrt{1+(\log (1+1/k))^{-1}}$$

Results: 2 → 1.86 → 1.82376 → 1.81313 → ... → 1.80899